# Field is not writeable: OpportunityPartner.Role

Tags: apex

I want to insert an opportunity partner with custom role into it .I am unable to insert an Opportunity Partner record as i am getting the following error "Field is not writeable: OpportunityPartner.Role".

Can any one provide me with same code for insert an OpportunityPartner record into salesforce using apex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot insert records in the [OpportunityPartner](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_opportunitypartner.htm) Object as it is read-only. You need to insert a record in the [Partner](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_partner.htm) object. When you insert a Partner recrod the OpportunityPartner is automatically created by the system. You can do this by using the below code.

```
partner p = new Partner();
p.OpportunityId = 'oppId';
p.AccountToId = 'AccId';
p.isPrimary = true;
p.Role = 'yourRole';//Make sure you have defined this in the Partner Roles (setup->Customize->Acc->partner roles)
insert p;
```